The JSON value > could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.id | LineNumber: 0 | > BytePositionInLine
I'm migrating from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json.
I was handling null id's no problem in Newtonsoft, just with this:
.AddNewtonsoftJson(x => 
{
   x.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore; 
})

Now I get the error:
{
   "$id":"1",
   "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
   "title":"One or more validation errors occurred.",
   "status":400,
   "errors":{
      "$id":"2",
      "$.id":[
         "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.id | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine:
10."
      ]
   },
   "traceId":"00-e707e5d67aedda844c575987294eaab8-50ccf58df2364c2a-00"
}

I think this is the migration suggestion for this case:

Newtonsoft.Json doesn't throw an exception in the following scenario:
NullValueHandling is set to Ignore, and During deserialization, the
JSON contains a null value for a non-nullable value type. In the same
scenario, System.Text.Json does throw an exception. (The corresponding
null-handling setting in System.Text.Json is
JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true.)
If you own the target type, the best workaround is to make the
property in question nullable (for example, change int to int?).

So I have made the field nullable:
[Serializable]
public abstract class Dto<TId> : DomainEntity<TId>
{
    [Key]
    public new TId? Id
    {
        get => (TId?)base.Id;
        set => base.Id = value;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public abstract class Dto : DomainEntity
{
}

[Serializable]
public abstract class DomainEntity<TId> : DomainEntity
{
    [Key]
    public TId? Id { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public abstract class DomainEntity
{
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public abstract class CreatedBySomeoneDto : Dto<int>
{
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedById { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class VgnItmDto : CreatedBySomeoneDto
{
    [Required]
    [Text(Boost = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Text(Boost = 0.5)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(3000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int IsNotVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;

    [Required]
    public int IsVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;

    [Required]
    public int RatingsCount { get; set; } = 0;

    public double? Rating { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    private Collection<int> _tags = new Collection<int>();

    [Required]
    [JsonPropertyName("tags")]
    public Collection<int> Tags => new Collection<int>(_tags);

    [JsonIgnore]
    private Collection<int> _secondaryTags = new Collection<int>();

    [JsonPropertyName("secondaryTags")]
    public Collection<int> SecondaryTags => new Collection<int>(_secondaryTags);

    [MaxLength(20)]
    [JsonIgnore]
    private Collection<ImageDto> _images = new Collection<ImageDto>();

    [JsonPropertyName("images")]
    public Collection<ImageDto> Images => new Collection<ImageDto>(_images);

    public int? PricePoint { get; set; }

    [Keyword]
    public string Discriminator { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(900)]
    public string WebPage { get; set; }

    public string Instagram { get; set; }

    public string Facebook { get; set; }

    public void UpdateTags(IEnumerable<int> tags)
    {
        _tags = new Collection<int>(tags.ToList());
    }

    public void UpdateSecondaryTags(IEnumerable<int> secondaryTags)
    {
        _secondaryTags = new Collection<int>(secondaryTags.ToList());
    }

    public void UpdateImages(IEnumerable<ImageDto> images)
    {
        _images = new Collection<ImageDto>(images.ToList());
    }
}

public class MenuItmDto : VgnItmDto
{
}

But I still get the error. Any idea why?
Here is the controller showing the type being sent in the json body of the HTTP request is a MenuItmDto:
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class VgnItmsController<TVgnItm, TVgnItmDto, TService> : ControllerBase
    where TVgnItm : VgnItm
    where TVgnItmDto : VgnItmDto
    where TService : IVgnItmsService<TVgnItm, TVgnItmDto>
{
    protected DbSet<TVgnItm> vgnItms;
    protected readonly VpDbContext context;
    protected readonly ExtendedVepoContext extendedContext;
    protected readonly TService service;

    public VgnItmsController(
        TService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    [HttpPost("create")]
    public async Task<ServiceResponse<TVgnItmDto>> AddVgnItm(TVgnItmDto vgnItm)
    {
        return await service.Add(vgnItm);
    }

[Route("menu-items")]
[ApiController]
public class MenuItmsController : VgnItmsController<MenuItm, MenuItmDto, IMenuItmsService>
{
    public MenuItmsController(
        VpDbContext context,
        ExtendedVepoContext extendedContext,
        IMenuItmsService service) :
        base(service)
    {
    }
}

Here is the HTTP request json body
{
   "id":null,
   "name":"a",
   "companyName":"a",
   "description":null,
   "tags":[
      20
   ],
   "secondaryTags":[
      
   ],
   "images":[
      
   ],
   "webPage":null,
   "instagram":null,
   "facebook":null,
   "rating":null,
   "ratingsCount":0,
   "isNotVeganCount":0,
   "isVeganCount":0,
   "pricePoint":null,
   "createdDate":null,
   "updatedDate":null,
   "createdById":null,
   "updatedById":null,
   "discriminator":"MenuItm"
}


NullValueHandling.Ignore would cause Json.NET to ignore a null value during deserialization even if the null value was invalid for assignment to the target because the target was a non-nullable value type.  System.Text.Json has no such feature.  You need to either make your properties nullable or introduce a generic converter factory that returns a default value for null.  See e.g. how to set default value for object property with default value when Json property is null?.

Does how to set default value for object property with default value when Json property is null? answer your question?


So I have made the field nullable:

The thing here is that you actually had not. For unconstrained generics when T is  a value type T and T? are the same (for more details see this answer), so for CreatedBySomeoneDto : Dto<int> the CreatedBySomeoneDto.Id is int, hence the error.
You can change the class declaration to CreatedBySomeoneDto : Dto<int?> and it should work (after making corresponding DateTime fields nullable too).
Another option would be restricting TId to struct - Dto<TId> : DomainEntity<TId> where TId : struct and DomainEntity<TId> : DomainEntity where TId : struct) but I suspect that this would not be an option for you.
Finally you can look into creating a custom converter which will return default for value types when encountering a null JSON token.
